# Error Starting Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am using the [Hyperledger-composer install guide](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools#Starting%20and%20stopping%20Hyperledger%20Fabric) to create the environemnet in aws ubuntu instance.

I get the following error:

```
    Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
    Running 'startFabric.sh'
    FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv1
    FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

#Detect architecture
ARCH=`uname -m`
uname -m

# Grab the current directory
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
 cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd
 dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

#

ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml down
Removing orderer.example.com ... done
Removing ca.org1.example.com ... done
Removing couchdb ... done
Removing network composer_default
ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml up -d
Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
Creating orderer.example.com ...
Creating ca.org1.example.com ...
Creating couchdb ...
Creating orderer.example.com
Creating couchdb
Creating orderer.example.com ... error

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.soCreating couchdb ... error

ERROR: for couchdb  Cannot start service couchdb: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: connect: connection Creating ca.org1.example.com ... error

ERROR: for ca.org1.example.com  Cannot start service ca.org1.example.com: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: connect: connection refused"

ERROR: for couchdb  Cannot start service couchdb: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: connect: connection refused"

ERROR: for ca.org1.example.com  Cannot start service ca.org1.example.com: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: connect: connection refused"

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: connect: connection refused"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The docker images are created properly.
How can I solve this error.

Comment: Is your Docker install OK?  Is the docker daemon started?  Is you user added to the docker group?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I destroyed  docker and re-installed.